# Dynamic destination phone assign, at incoming call start

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am looking into the possibility to implement call tracking with Twilio.

What I would need is that right at the start of an incoming call I would like to be able to change the destination number for that call. 
How is this achievable with Twilio via API?

Reading the API docs I found the that there is a real-time call and message routing feature ([here](https://www.twilio.com/use-cases/call-tracking)) and followed the example ([here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/call-tracking/php/laravel)) but it's not what I would like to achieve.

Thanks ahead for any suggestion and help!

--Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You absolutely can dynamically change the destination number for calls on Twilio. When you are forwarding calls you [use the `<Dial>` noun in TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) like so:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>YOUR_NUMBER_HERE</Dial>
</Response>
```

However, if you serve your TwiML dynamically you can return whatever number in the `<Dial>` tag that you want, based on whatever conditions you want. For example in Ruby using Sinatra:

```
post "/voice" do
  if params["From"] === SOME_SPECIAL_NUMBER
    number = FORWARDING_NUMBER_1
  else
    number = FORWARDING_NUMBER_2
  end
  "<Response>
    <Dial>#{number}</Dial>
  </Response>"
end
```

Let me know if this helps at all.